# Pick a color in tikzpicture from

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to extend this code snippet

```
\newcommand\progskills[1]{ 
    \renewcommand{\progskills}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %\node [above right] at (0, 4) {$0 \: LOC \: \arrow{3.2} \: 5000 \: LOC$};
        \foreach [count=\i] \x/\y in {#1}{
            \draw[fill=maingray,maingray] (0,\i) rectangle (6,\i+0.4);
            \draw[fill=white,mainblue](0,\i) rectangle (\y,\i+0.4);
            \node [above right] at (0,\i+0.35) {\x};
        }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}
```

To cycle through a list of colors. In Python-Matplotlib I would use e.g. `itertools.cycle` on an array of colors and index the array. How can I achieve such behavior using latex and tkzpicture?

The naive snippet below does not work. The command creates "skillbars" and originates from [twentyseconds CV](https://github.com/spagnuolocarmine/TwentySecondsCurriculumVitae-LaTex)

```
\newcommand\labskills[1]{ 
    \renewcommand{\labskills}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\mycolors{lightgray, materialcyan, orange, green, materialorange, materialteal, materialamber, materialindigo, materialgreen, materiallime}
        %\node [above right] at (0, 4) {$0 \: LOC \: \arrow{3.2} \: 5000 \: LOC$};

        \foreach [count=\i] \x/\y in {#1}{
            \draw[fill=maingray,maingray] (0,\i) rectangle (6,\i+0.4);
            \draw[fill=white, \mycolors[\i]](0,\i) rectangle (\y,\i+0.4);
            \node [above right] at (0,\i+0.35) {\x};
        }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you only post fragments. Here is a generic example, not using your colors or macros because from your question it is not clear how they are defined. If you define the list of colors with quotes around the entries,

```
\def\mycolors{"red","blue","purple"}
```

you can cycle through the colors via

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\mycolors}[Mod(\i-1,3)]}
```

where `3` is the length of the above list. The following is a complete compilable example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\labskills[1]{ 
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\mycolors{"red","blue","purple"}
        \foreach [count=\i] \x/\y in {#1}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\mycolors}[Mod(\i-1,3)]}
            \draw[fill=gray,gray] (0,\i) rectangle (6,\i+0.4);
            \draw[fill=white, \mycolor](0,\i) rectangle (\y,\i+0.4);
            \node [above right] at (0,\i+0.35) {\x};
        }
        \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\labskills{Meowing/4,Purring/3,Catching mice/4,Hibernating/1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot. I will update my question to provide a minimal working exmple